# SQL Logic Needed for SSRS - Greatest Date Entry From Multiple Results

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a situation where there are two table SS and SSUSED. Table SS lists all tickets that have a finite number of uses. Table two, SSUSED contains entries for all of the tickets in table SS. I need to gather certain information from both tables HOWEVER, I only need to grab data from the row in table SSUSED that has the most recent date. That column is usedate.

My code brings back the values specified from all of the usage rows in table SSUSED. Can someone please help with the logic for only retrieving the fields desired from the latest entry in SSUSED.

```
SELECT        SS.memid, SS.initialdate, SS.dateexpire, SS.initialquantity, SS.usedquantity, PRODUCTS.description, EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS trainlname, EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS trainfname, SS.ssid

FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid

WHERE (SS.initialdate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rank order the SSUSED records with a derived column. Then join that table with your data and use the most recent indicator in your join fields.

```
;WITH MostRecentSSUSED AS
(
    SELECT ssid, employeid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ssid DESC) AS MostRecentID
    FROM
        SSUSED
)

SELECT        SS.memid, SS.initialdate, SS.dateexpire, SS.initialquantity, SS.usedquantity, PRODUCTS.description, EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS trainlname, EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS trainfname, SS.ssid

FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                         PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                         MostRecentSSUSED SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid AND SSUSED.MostRecentID = 1 INNER JOIN
                         EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid

WHERE (SS.initialdate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate)
```

You can also try it another way. Depending on the size of SSUSED, the query below may be more efficient as portions of the data would be filtered out first and then ranked.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
(
    SELECT        SS.memid, SS.initialdate, SS.dateexpire, SS.initialquantity, SS.usedquantity, PRODUCTS.description, EMPLOYEES_1.lname AS trainlname, EMPLOYEES_1.fname AS trainfname, SS.ssid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ssid DESC) AS MostRecentID

    FROM            SS INNER JOIN
                             PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid INNER JOIN
                             MostRecentSSUSED SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid  INNER JOIN
                             EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid

    WHERE (SS.initialdate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate) 
)AS X
WHERE 
    X.MostRecentID = 1
```